# While controller in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a scenario to test.Request 1(a SOAP/XML request) generates Response which has a field, say `totaldocsperpage`. Based on that field, the same Request 1 has to be run that many times as of the `totaldocsperpage`, with `pagenum` (a variable field in request 1) incrementing from 1 to `totaldocsperpage`.

How this can be achieved? I extracted the `totaldocsperpage` using Regex extractor and used a while controller in the beginning with the below condition

```
${__javaScript("${pagenum}" < "${totaldocsperpage}")}
```

with `pagenum` as the counter name I have given for incrementing page number in the Request 1.

I want this to run `totaldocsperpage` times and stop. But it just runs infinitely. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you [comparing numbers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) in condition you don't need quotes, also use [`__jexl3`](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) or `__groovy` instead of `__javaScript`

> Checking this and using __jexl3 or __groovy function in Condition is advised for performances

```
${__jexl3(${pagenum} > ${totaldocsperpage})}
```

Comment: As an extension to my previous question, I was using the same for multi threads. When I tried with the below tree structure, the counter is not running correctly for all the 10 customers. The counter stops as soon as it finds a match from any of the customers. But I need to loop through all the pages for all customers at the same time. Please advise.

1.Threadgroup--with 10 threads
  A.While Controller  ${__javaScript(${pagenum} < ${totalpages})}
    a.Request
      i.Regex extractor(totalpages)
      ii.Counter(pagenum)
      iii. CSV Data set config(customer)

Comment: Please ask a new question

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove quotation marks from your expression:

   ```
   ${__javaScript(${pagenum} < ${totaldocsperpage})}
   ```
2. Check *jmeter.log* file for any suspicions entries
3. It might be a better idea to go for [XPath Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) given you receive XML-based response